# Master from split view controller is showed over the tab bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a tab bar controller with three tabs that I set programmatically. The two first ones are just `UIViewController` but the third one is an `UISplitViewController` that I get from another storyboard. Everything works great but when I'm on portrait mode and show the master view, this one is showed on top of the tab bar. I would like keep showing the full tab bar.

[image]

This also generate problems when trying to show an `UIAlertController` from an item bar button in the master view (this button doesn't exist in the image) as the popover is showed behind the master view.

Does anyone know how can I workaround this?

The way I set them programmatically is this (in case it may help):

```
UIViewController *view1 = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstView"];
UIViewController *view2 = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondView"];

UIViewController *view3 = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardSplit" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MySplitView"];

UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)view3;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
splitViewController.delegate = self;

NSMutableArray *tabViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[tabViewControllers addObject:view1];
[tabViewControllers addObject:view2];
[tabViewControllers addObject:splitViewController];

[self setViewControllers:tabViewControllers];

view1.tabBarItem =
[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"view1"
                              image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"view1"]
                                tag:1];
view2.tabBarItem =
[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"view2"
                              image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"view2"]
                                tag:2];
view3.tabBarItem =
[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"view3"
                              image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"view3"]
                                tag:3];
```

Comment: I think it's ok. You can hide it with swipe left. In landscape orientation all is fine.

Comment: According to the docs a `UISplitViewController` must always be the root view controller. On your case the tab view controller is the root.

Comment: UISplitViewController need not always be the root as of iOS 8. See [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15118)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try importing QuartzCore, then setting TabBarController.tabBar.layer.zposition = 1. Of course replacing the necessaries like tabBar with the name of your tab bar and so on. 
This is works in Swift however through your own initiative you can work this into Obj-C

Comment: Thanks. It will make the work, but wouldn't it keep hiding part of the last row if the master view is a long list?

Comment: I don't believe so, I haven't used this in a tab bar but I have in a navigation bar and what this effectively does is set the to the very front of everything until told otherwise.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to clarify where you are setting the zPosition on the tab bar? Is it in a UISplitViewControllerDelegate method for example? Perhaps in viewDidLoad() of the UITabBarController? I have tried this suggestion is many places however the the master view controller continues to appear above the tab bar controller.

Comment: This did not work for me, however when the iPad is in landscape mode, it is correctly shown behind the tabbar without adding code. This only doesn't work in portrait, but that's not needed for my case.